# Solve the equation for maximum damping effect

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I have a waveform as below characteristics;

[image: waveform]

I need this wave to be damped very quicly. So I though maybe I can feed it to opposite phase and the cancel each other after one period. As below;

[image: damped waveform]

But I wanted to go into detail and calculate the damper (antiphase) signals amplitude (0.9) in above waveform to make it the best damper it can be. To do that, I believe I need to solve below equation for to give minimum.

[image: formula]

And I feel like the unknown **c** must be derivaed from f to give the best result. But I do not know how to solve this. I tried taking the derivative of it by t, but it failed. Because there are so many unknowns in the equation. Can someone give me some pointers on this?

To summarize, I have this oscillation waveform slowly fading, I need it to be faded instantly after its first period (after 1/f time passed).

Comment: Since you are looking only at values of $x>0$, why do you keep a $sgn(x)$ in your function. It is always $sgn(x)=1$

Comment: Because I can only introduce the damping enhancer signal after 1/f time. But I get you, I am only interested after 1/f time to be minimized in rms value.. Just don't know how to represent it.